# How can you write less, repetitive code for a useReducer hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I am creating a useReducer that, e.g., sets the price of an item.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_PRICE': 
        return {
          ...state,
          price: action.payload,
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

I now have to have multiple of these SET_PRICE, as I have hundreds of products, so I started writing

```
case 'SET_PRICE_0': 
        return {
          ...state,
          price_0: action.payload,
        }
case 'SET_PRICE_1': 
        return {
          ...state,
          price_1: action.payload,
        }
      ...
```

I can see that there's something wrong if I write over 10 of these, let alone 100... Is there an alternative to write less code?

Comment: please post the initial state you are using + how come you want to set the price of all products at once ? either you should have in the action each product with the price or when the user types the price for each product you set it

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna refactor your code. This approach, case 'SET_PRICE_1, will not scale. Can you post an example of  Api response?
Depending on your data structure, you should have something like:

```
products: [
  {
    productName: 'productName',
    price: '$$$',
  },
]
```

or maybe

```
 products: {
   [productName]: {
     price: '$$$',
   } 
 }
```

in case, you just need the product price (this will not scale too),

```
  productPrices: {
    [productName]: '$$$'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is not with the reducer you have mentioned, but the way you're using it. While rendering the products, you should use `useReducer` hook with the first reducer (the one with SET_PRICE) while mounting each product component.

Here's a dummy implementation:

```
const ProductComponent = () => {
    const [price, setPrice] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <div> ... </div>
    );
};
```

And then you can map on your products list with this component.

You can also refer to this detailed article on different `useReducer` recipes: https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-use-usereducer-in-react-hooks-for-performance-optimization-ecafca9e7bf5